# Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out error

Tags: java, apache-axis

I am trying to connect to a webservice from my application and I am getting following exception :

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 30000 ms
                at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:197)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
                at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
                at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
                at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
                at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)

Caused by: org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 30000 ms
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:155)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:130)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
                at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
                ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
                at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:367)
                at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:524)
                at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:545)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor197.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:140)
                ... 35 more
```

I am not overwriting timeout interval in my application.
Can anyone please tell me through which property this timeout is configured ?and in which place its configured ? I thought its configured in axis2.xml But i might be wrong

Comment: This might sound obvious, but does the webserver you are trying to connect to is actually available? You did not do any typo in the url? Did you use the right port? Because, at least for me, the most common problem of  a connect time out is always one of these ^^

Comment: @Florian Schöffl  My question was different and simple. If you see the stacktrace , its saying currently timeout has been set to "30000". I just want to know in which place its configured

Comment: Ah damn, I totaly misread that. Yes, you are looking for the CONNECTION_TIMEOUT parameter that is, indeed, inside the axis2.xml.

Comment: @FlorianSchöffl Thanks for confirming that . But wondering how its set to 30000. I have not set it anywhere in my code and default value of that property is 0. If you can provide any input it will be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not realy sure what you promise of it, but the default timeout of 30 seconds is set in the sourcecode of axis2.

To be precisely in **org.apache.axis2.client.Options** on line 118 (axis2 version 1.7.4):

```
public static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 30 * 1000;
```

This default value will be used if the timout is not set manually and has its default value of -1 (line 504 eg).

```
    return timeOutInMilliSeconds == -1 ? DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS
            : timeOutInMilliSeconds;
```

If you want to overwrite the timeout I will refer you to the [axis documentation](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#timeout_config)